# Laravel 5: route optional parameter issue

Tags: laravel-routing

I want to have second param as optional one.

Routes:

```
Route::get('/offers/preview/{id}/{string?}', 'OfferController@preview');
```

Controller:

```
public function preview($id, $string)
{
    // some code
}
```

Calling "offers/preview/101/test" looks ok.

Error by calling "offers/preview/101"

```
ErrorException in OfferController.php line 53:
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\OfferController::preview()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add default value for $string in your function. (eg. $string = '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add default value for the optional paramaters

```
public function preview($id, $string = '')
{
   // some code
}
```

see [Laravel Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)